# Convert JSON array to native integer array

Tags: postgresql, array, postgresql-10

My function is returning json data which is containing two integer array.
Now I need to get this two integer array list  and passed it to another function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION method1(id integer)
RETURNS JSON
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
VOLATILE
PARALLEL UNSAFE
COST 100
AS $BODY$DECLARE

RETURN json_build_object(foo:'{1,2,3}',bar:'{10,20,30}');
END;
$BODY$;
```

I am calling this function to another function using

```
select * into json_data from 
method1(1);
```

Now I need to pass json_data->foo as a integer list to another function.
How Can i do that?

Comment: I have updated that thing. it was my typing mistake

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37686187 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/48253954